# StackOverflow not showing question list and shows incorrect number of tagged question count

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags

I'm a regular user of `StackOverflow`. When I today logged-in to **StackOverflow** the question lists are not showing and the total question count for iOS tag is showing as zero.

[image: Incorrect question list and count]

I refreshed many times and it is not showing me the data. Please help me, thanks in advance.

**Additional information:**

I'm using Firefox with version 22.0. (The same was working for me till yesterday)

I checked it for Meta, but it is working correctly for `Meta StackOverflow`, I have the issue only for `StackOverflow`.